# I have a batch sheet and a recipe sheet I want to create a production sheet based on that in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

| Batch ID | Product ID | Quantity | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123A | Cake123 | 1000g | 3/01/2024 |
| 567B | Muffin345 | 1000g | 3/01/2023 |

Recipe Sheet looks like this

| Recipe ID | Product ID | Ingredient ID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Cake123 | flour123 | 100g |
| DEF456 | Muffin345 | chips345 | 100g |

Now I want my production sheet to look like

| Batch ID | Product ID | Ingredient ID | Quantity Used | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123A | Cake123 | flour123 | 1000g | 3/01/2024 |
| 567B | Muffin345 | chips345 | 1000g | 3/01/2024 |

But I want this automated through Google Apps Script but don't know how

Comment: Can you please share it in a spreadsheet and show us what you have worked/researched on? this can also be done using formula.

Comment: Need more example data to get an idea of the complete problem.

Comment: We are not a code writing service.  If you have specific questions about  the code feel free to ask them, otherwise plan to develop most of the code on your own.

Comment: why is the date for Batch 567B changed from 3/1/2023 to 3/1/2024?

Comment: @Cooper https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uKx5E4sVIjm7dorRZhKyI2EiqTWw25iYLhcGmO22RlY/edit?usp=sharing
Here is a link to the spreadsheet 
I acknowledge that this may not be the coding forum so let me rephrase my question 
When I add rows to 'Batch ID' sheet I want the 'Production ID' sheet to add rows based on the recipe from 'Recipe ID' sheet 
What is the best possible way to achieve this outcome? 
PS. apologies that should be 2024

Comment: Please post you code in the question.  Personally, I do not follow links to offsite resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=reduce(tocol(,1),indirect("'Batch ID '!B2:B"&xmatch("?*",'Batch ID '!B:B,2,-1)),lambda(a,c,if(c="",tocol(,1),let(Σ,filter({'Recipe ID '!B:C,offset(c,,1)/100*'Recipe ID '!D:D},'Recipe ID '!B:B=c),iferror(vstack(a,hstack(wrapcols(offset(c,,-1),rows(Σ),offset(c,,-1)), Σ, wrapcols(offset(c,,2),rows(Σ),offset(c,,2)))))))))
```

[image]